# Find out number of bits needed to represent a positive integer in binary?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

This is probably pretty basic, but to save me an hour or so of grief can anyone tell me how you can work out the number of bits required to represent a given positive integer in Java?

e.g. I get a decimal 11, (1011). I need to get the answer, 4.

I figured if I could work out how to set all the bits other than the most significant bit to 0, and then >>> it, I'd get my answer. But... I can't.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well, you can just count how many times you shift right before you're left with just zero:

```
int value = 11;
int count = 0;
while (value > 0) {
    count++;
    value = value >> 1;
}
```

Comment: d'oh! yes that's pretty simple. I was expecting some great bit-twiddling wizardry... Thanks for the quick reply, I'll use that for now, but I'd be interested to see if there are any methods without loops and the such.

Comment: Well, you could unroll the loop since it should be bounded at 32 iterations (or 64--however Java works).

Comment: int is 32 bits in Java, long is 64.

Comment: OK, I posted you a method with no loop. It still requires a few steps though ;).

Comment: Not so good for negatives. Try `while (value != 0) { ++count; value >>>= 1; }`. >>> is the logical (no sign-extension) right shift operator.

Comment: @whataheck `>> 1` divides by 2 rounding down to minus infinity (so -1 "divided by 2" is still -1). `>>> 1` treats the number as if it was positive (unsigned) and divides by 2.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline ok .. but when I try to  use  value >> 1;
 in my program,thers a compliation error "value >> 1 " is not a statement.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline Also >> 1 is for negative numbers ,but in java we dont have unsigned numbers so every number though its a negative one is represented in bits before this operation takes place ,,.. then why do we have 2 operators one for positive and other for negative numbers ..

Comment: @whataheck `value >> 1` is an expression, not a statement. So you'd need to do something like `value = value >> 1;` or `value >>= 1;` (where a statement is valid). `>>` and `>>>` work on both positive numbers, and produce the same results. The difference is how they treat negative numbers. Assembly languages typically have two mnemonics, such as `ASR` and `LSR` for arithmetic and logical shift right.

Answer (score 35):

Well, the answer is pretty simple. If you have an int value:

```
int log2(int value) {
    return Integer.SIZE - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(value);
}
```

The same exists for Long...

[Edit]
If shaving milliseconds is an issue here, Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(int) is reasonably efficient, but still does 15 operations... Expanding a reasonable amount of memory (300 bytes, static) you could shave that to between 1 and 8 operations, depending on the range of your integers.

Comment: This is the fastest solution.  And far easier to follow than the accepted answer!

Comment: This may be the fastest solution but technically speaking it is not foolproof. Try calling it with value = 0, the result is: 0. This is wrong for 2 reasons: first of all, mathematically speaking log2(0) is undefined. Second, in the context of the original question: when you want to store an integer whose value is zero you will need at least one bit to do so.

Comment: If that is the only issue it can be special cased, and still be easier to understand and more performant than the other answers.

Comment: Out of the javadoc: Note that this method is closely related to the logarithm base 2. For all positive int values x: 

`floor(log2(x)) = 31 - numberOfLeadingZeros(x)` 
`ceil(log2(x)) = 32 - numberOfLeadingZeros(x - 1)`

Answer (score 27):

My Java is a bit rusty, but the language-agnostic answer (if there is a "log2" function and a "floor" function available) would be:

```
numberOfBits = floor(log2(decimalNumber))+1
```

Assuming that "decimalNumber" is greater than 0. If it is 0, you just need 1 bit.

Comment: I think decimalNumber should be decimalNumber + 1.  log_2 256 is 8, whereas it needs 9 bits to represent.  log_2 0 is undefined, but it needs zero bits to represent.

Comment: @strager: I think you were close. I needed to use "floor" instead of "ceil", then add a +1. Obviously, a check is needed for "decimalNumber == 0" first. For example, try out 255 (which should give 8).

Comment: @gnovice, Ah, good.  I wasn't sure myself.  Thanks for looking into it.  =]

Comment: It doesn't work for negative integers ofcourse, and sometimes you have to count bitcount for those aswell :) However, if you're compacting data, then I think a better approach would be to store a bit denoting sign, then storing the absolute value of that, since -1 would take up 32 bits where 1 would take up 2 (1 for the 1, and one for the sign).

Comment: @Statement: What you say makes sense, but the OP said they were only looking to get bit counts for positive integers.

Answer (score 15):

Integer.toBinaryString(number).length();

Good grief... why the down votes?

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(final String[] argv)
    {
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0).length());
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(1).length());
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(2).length());
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(3).length());
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(4).length());
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(5).length());
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(6).length());
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(7).length());
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(8).length());
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(9).length());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
3
3
4
4
```

Here is a simple test for the speed of the various solutions:

```
public class Tester 
{
    public static void main(final String[] argv) 
    {
        final int size;
        final long totalA;
        final long totalB;
        final long totalC;
        final long totalD;

        size = 100000000;

        totalA = test(new A(), size);
        totalB = test(new B(), size);
        totalC = test(new C(), size);
        totalD = test(new D(), size);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Total D = " + totalD + " ms");
        System.out.println("Total B = " + totalB + " ms");
        System.out.println("Total C = " + totalC + " ms");
        System.out.println("Total A = " + totalA + " ms");

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Total B = " + (totalB / totalD) + " times slower");
        System.out.println("Total C = " + (totalC / totalD) + " times slower");
        System.out.println("Total A = " + (totalA / totalD) + " times slower");
    }

    private static long test(final Testable tester, 
                             final int      size)
    {
        final long start;
        final long end;
        final long total;

        start = System.nanoTime();
        tester.test(size);
        end   = System.nanoTime();
        total = end - start;

        return (total / 1000000);
    }

    private static interface Testable
    {
        void test(int size);
    }

    private static class A
        implements Testable
    {
        @Override
        public void test(final int size)
        {
            int value;

            value = 0;

            for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
            {
                value += Integer.toBinaryString(i).length();
            }

            System.out.println("value = " + value);
        }    
    }

    private static class B
        implements Testable
    {
        @Override
        public void test(final int size)
        {
            int total;

            total = 0;

            for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
            {
                int value = i;
                int count = 0;

                while (value > 0) 
                {
                    count++;
                    value >>= 1;
                }

                total += count;
            }

            System.out.println("total = " + total);
        }    
    }

    private static class C
        implements Testable
    {
        @Override
        public void test(final int size)
        {
            int total;
            final double log2;

            total = 0;
            log2  = Math.log(2);

            for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
            {
                final double logX;
                final double temp;

                logX   = Math.log(i);
                temp   = logX / log2;                
                total += (int)Math.floor(temp) + 1;
            }

            System.out.println("total = " + total);
        }    
    }

    private static class D
        implements Testable
    {
        @Override
        public void test(final int size)
        {
            int total;

            total = 0;

            for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
            {
                total += 32-Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(i);
            }

            System.out.println("total = " + total);
        }    
    }
}
```

Output on my machine is:

```
value = -1729185023
total = -1729185023
total = -1729185023
total = -1729185023

Total D = 118 ms
Total B = 1722 ms
Total C = 4462 ms
Total A = 5704 ms

Total B = 14 times slower
Total C = 37 times slower
Total A = 48 times slower
```

For those of you complaining about speed... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#Quotes.

Write the program to be readable first, then find out where it is slow, then make it faster.  Before and after you optimize test the change.  If the change wasn't large enough for the expense of making the code less readable don't bother with the change.

Comment: You probably got the down votes because your solution is incredible expensive.

Comment: didn't ask for it to be quick :-)

Comment: It would seem that doing it 100,000,000 (on my desktop) probably would not be a bottleneck in a "real" program.

Comment: Very nice benchmark! For the sake of completeness, you could add `BigInteger.valueOf(i).bitLength()` (which is on the slow side: on my machine, about 5 or 6 times slower than your **D**)

Comment: However, `BigInteger.bitLength()` is **bugged and unreliable** (at least in Java 6). http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=c134915207cae78f258c98a958f3?bug_id=6910473

Answer (score 11):

Taking the two based log of the number will report the number of bits required to store it.

Comment: A) -2 rep won't kill you  B) this probably was in an audit and was a little ambiguous for the subject of the audit and was downvoted so it wouldn't ding someone again.

Comment: so I guess it's `int(log2(n)) + 1`

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to avoid a loop and you care about speed, you can use a method like this:

```
int value = ...;
int count = 0;
if( value < 0 ) { value = 0; count = 32; }
if( value >= 0x7FFF ) { value >>= 16; count += 16; }
if( value >= 0x7F ) { value >>= 8; count += 8; }
if( value >= 0x7 ) { value >>= 4; count += 4; }
if( value >= 0x3 ) { value >>= 2; count += 2; }
if( value >= 0x1 ) { value >>= 1; count += 1; }
```

Java doesn't have unsigned integers, so that first if( value < 0 ) is a little questionable. Negative numbers always set the most significant bit, so arguably require the full word to to represent them. Adapt that behavior if you care.

Incidentally, to handle a 64-bit integer, replace the if( value < 0 ) line with these two:

```
if( value < 0 ) { value = 0; count = 64; }
if( value >= 0x7FFFFFFF ) { value >>= 32; count += 32; }
```

Comment: this gives wrong results. for value = 4, this returns 2 when it should be 3. In fact it never outputs 3 at all, it skips straight to 4 at value =8.

Comment: My apologies. The > signs should have been >= signs. I believe it should work now.

Answer (score 4):

For non-negative values, probably the most direct answer is:

```
java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(value).bitLength()
```

(For negative numbers it will give the bit length of one less than the absolute value, rather than infinity you'd expect from two's complement notation.)

Comment: Not really *the bit length of the absolute value*:
`System.out.println(BigInteger.valueOf(-1).bitLength());` prints 0, not 1

Comment: @UnaiVivi Um yes. Corrected. It'd probably be better if the method threw `IllegalStateException` for negative values rather than doing something a bit strange.

Comment: Do you have an idea why they did it that way (for negative numbers)? I can't see any usefulness the way they did it...

Comment: @UnaiVivi I believe if you add one you will get the minimum number of bits needed to represent the value in two's complement notation.

Answer (score 1):

This is in C, but I suspect you could convert to Java fairly easily:

[Find the log base 2 of an N-bit integer in O(lg(N)) operations](http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add some other alternatives, just for the sake of completeness:

**1** `BigInteger.valueOf(i).bitLength()`

Not very fast. Furthermore, `BigInteger.bitLength()` it's bugged and unreliable (fixed in Java7), since when more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` bits are needed (freakishly high input number needed!! [such as 1 left-shifted `Integer.MAX_VALUE` times, aka `2^Integer.MAX_VALUE`]) the result overflows and negative numbers appear for the next `2^(2*Integer.MAX_VALUE)-2^Integer.MAX_VALUE` numbers, which is a number so high your head could explode. Note that it is estimated the universe containes some 10^80 atoms; that number is `2^4G` (`G` as in Giga, `1024*1024*1024`).

**2**

```
static int neededBits(int i)
{
    assert i > 0;
    int res;
    int sh;
    res = ((i > 0xFFFF) ? 1 : 0) << 4;
    i >>= res;
    sh = ((i > 0xFF) ? 1 : 0) << 3;
    i >>= sh;
    res |= sh;
    sh = ((i > 0xF) ? 1 : 0) << 2;
    i >>= sh;
    res |= sh;
    sh = ((i > 0x3) ? 1 : 0) << 1;
    i >>= sh;
    res |= sh;
    res |= (i >> 1);
    return res + 1;
}
```

A very fast solution, but still half as fast as ye olde `32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(i);`.

Answer (score 1):

Binary search over the the exponents of 2 is faster than the bit shift ([top voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/680012/5983976)) solution, which might be valuable if the numbers are huge (thousands of decimal digits), you know the maximum available bits and you do not want to generate the tables:

```
    int  minExpVal   = 0;
    int  maxExpVal   = 62;
    int  medExpVal   = maxExpVal >> 1;
    long medianValue = 0l;

    while (maxExpVal - minExpVal > 1) {
        medianValue = 1l << medExpVal;
        if (value > medianValue) {
            minExpVal = medExpVal;
        } else {
            maxExpVal = medExpVal;
        }
        medExpVal = (minExpVal + maxExpVal) >> 1;
    }

    return value == 1l << maxExpVal ?  maxExpVal  + 1 : maxExpVal;
```

However, the solution using the leading zeros would be still by far faster:

```
return Long.SIZE - Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(value);
```

Benchmarks:

```
Leading zeros time is: 2 ms
BinarySearch time is: 95 ms
BitShift time is: 135 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me!

```
int numberOfBitsRequired(int n)
{
    return (int)Math.floor(Math.log(n)/Math.log(2)) + 1;
}
```

To include negative numbers as well, you can add an extra bit and use it to specify the sign.

```
public static int numberOfBitsRequiredSigned(int n)
{
    return (int)Math.floor(Math.log(Math.abs(n))/Math.log(2)) + 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this, if you don't want to modify the original value.

```
unsigned int value = 11;
unsigned int count = 0;
if(value > 0)
{
    for(int i=1;i<value;i*=2) // multiply by two => shift one to left
    {
        ++count;
    }
}
```

Note: Let the compiler worry about turning `i*=2` into a bit shift operation to improve performance.

For the visual thinkers among us:

```
64 32 16  8  4  2  1
 0  0  0  1  0  1  1  -> binary representation of decimal number 'value' = 11 (=1+2+8)
```

We start with `i=1` at the right.
Then we keep multiplying by two, for as long as `i < value`.
In the meanwhile, we keep track of how many bits we went to the left.

So in this example, as soon as `i` reaches 16 the value is larger than 11, and thus we stop. And we will then have counted 4 bits: `1 *2 *2 *2 *2 = 16 (=2^4)`.

**Careful with signed numbers.** When dealing with signed numbers that may be positive or negative, you would first have to multiply the negative numbers by -1. Additionally, you would have to consider how you want to take the sign-bit into account.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
public static int getNumberOfBits(int N) {
    int bits = 0;
        while(Math.pow(2, bits) <= N){
           bits++;
       }
       return bits;
}
```

I know you are looking for a way to not use loops, but I feel this is pretty strait forward otherwise since bits are just a two to the power of a number.

Answer (score -1):

```
(int) Math.ceil((Math.log(n) / Math.log(2))
```

Of course this only works for positive integers.

Comment: This gives the wrong result for n = 128. It outputs 7 when it should be 8