# Find out how many binary digits a particular integer has

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compute fast log base 2 ceiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272424/compute-fast-log-base-2-ceiling)

What is the fastest possible way to find out how many binary digits a particular integer has when it is converted from decimal to binary in C/C++?

Ex. 47<sub>(10)</sub> = 101111<sub>(2)</sub>

So 47 has 6 digits represented in binary.

Comment: You basically want to [compute ceil(log2(n))](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272424/compute-fast-log-base-2-ceiling), which has already been asked here.

Comment: _BitScanReverse (MSVC) or equivalent. Anything that calculates a floating point logarithm is instantly disqualified when asking for the fastest way.

Comment: The fastest way will depend on the processor, but you can find gcc and MS solutions that will use a cpu instruction here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272424/compute-fast-log-base-2-ceiling

Comment: This is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272424/compute-fast-log-base-2-ceiling.  The requested function transitions at different locations.  It is, however, a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721244/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-calculate-the-number-of-bits-needed-to-store-a-number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fastest solution that's presented at [my favorite collection of bit twiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) is [Find the log base 2 of an N-bit integer in O(lg(N)) operations with multiply and lookup](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogDeBruijn). It requires 13 instructions to find the highest set bit in a number.

```
uint32_t v; // find the log base 2 of 32-bit v
int r;      // result goes here

static const int MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[32] = 
{
  0, 9, 1, 10, 13, 21, 2, 29, 11, 14, 16, 18, 22, 25, 3, 30,
  8, 12, 20, 28, 15, 17, 24, 7, 19, 27, 23, 6, 26, 5, 4, 31
};

v |= v >> 1; // first round down to one less than a power of 2 
v |= v >> 2;
v |= v >> 4;
v |= v >> 8;
v |= v >> 16;

r = MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[(uint32_t)(v * 0x07C4ACDDU) >> 27];
```

Comment: While I think this ORing method is cool (and as a programmer I can appreciate it artistically), it's not optimal. You doing 10 operations worth of OR and SHIFT, then your doing a MUL with another SHIFT, then your doing a memory look-up (LUT). It'd say this is as slow as the Log2 methods that were proposed.

Comment: @LastCoder What are you envisioning log2 to be doing behind the scenes? This implementation openly admits it needs 13 (non-FP) instructions.

Comment: If the target architecture has a fast cache then the LUT shouldn't be too expensive.

Comment: Just measured on my Intel i7-based MacBook Pro. 1,000,000 iterations of ceil(log2(n)) took 33,132 microseconds, and 1,000,000 iterations of the bit-twiddling version took 8,410 microseconds--right around 75% faster.

Comment: How about the x87-FPU instruction FYL2XP1. This is what I expect Log2 to use on all x86 & x86-64 bit machines. It would put the number in ST(0) and it would put the constant 1 in ST(1), then execute FYL2XP1, which does ST0 = ST1 * log2( ST0 + 1.0 ), then you'd pop/store ST(0) as an integer again. So that would be 4 instructions total for the optimal FPU version.

Comment: Code published at https://github.com/sblom/sandbox/blob/master/try/cpp/binary_digit_count.cpp

Comment: @LastCoder, yes--4 instructions, but since they're FP instructions, any one may take longer than the entire 32-bit int algorithm.

Comment: @sblom - I wrote the 3 function (BSR, FPU, and OR) in assembly and benched them. I got the following results: (312ms BSR, 2949ms FPU, 686ms OR) using 0x7FFFFFF runs each. So, the OR method is 75% faster than FPU and the BSR method is 50% faster than OR. http://snipt.org/xrkn5 FASM was the assembler used. SO I WAS OVERZEALOUS/WRONG assuming that this OR method was as slow as FPU.

Comment: @sblom - Extra note for completeness, the branching method IFs that I noted in my post is also faster than the OR method, but slower than BSR instruction. http://snipt.org/xrom3 (312ms BSR, 406ms IFs, 671ms OR)

Comment: @LastCoder, Didn't even know the BSR instruction before today. That's extremely neat. Thanks for the knowledge boost!

Answer (score 11):

For a quick fun way of doing this without needing to call math functions, check this one out:

```
for (digits = 0; val > 0; val >>= 1)
        digits++;
```

As a bonus, this should cook down to a memory load and 2 registers in use, for extra whiz-bang.

Comment: I think this is the best answer so far..

Comment: Nice and simple. With linear complexity.

Comment: Too simple. OP said "fastest way", not "simplest" (is this really any simpler than using an intrinsic function anyway?)

Comment: This is not the "fastest possible way" so there's a divide between the OP 's question and what he marked as the accepted answer. Maybe this is a language barrier or "fastest possible way" means the fastest to type rather the fastest with regards to execution?...

Comment: The OP wasn't too specific about what was meant by "fastest".  This could easily be the fastest solution given the right dataset, computer architecture, and/or compile-time optimizations.  It's definitely the fastest for me to comprehend.

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking for the "fastest" way in terms of performance, you will need to resort to platform-specific methods.

Some architectures actually have an instruction that does that.

On x86, you have the `bsr` instruction.

**In MSVC, it is accessible as:**

```
inline int bitlength(unsigned long x){
    if (x == 0)
        return 0;

    unsigned long index;
    _BitScanReverse(&index,x);
    return (int)(index + 1);
}
```

**GCC** has the [`__builtin_clz()` intrinsic](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) - which does something similar.

Comment: This is the answer that should be marked correct (also it came in a minute before mine). The BSR opcode is the fastest method for x86, in the general case the branching IF statements would likely be fastest.

Comment: Extra note for completeness, the branching method IFs that I noted in my post is also faster than the ORing method (in another answer), but slower than BSR instruction. snipt.org/xrom3 (312ms BSR, 406ms IFs, 671ms OR) I used FlatAssembler to benchmark the functions.

Answer (score 4):

The traditional way

```
int count = 32;
for(int i = 1 << 31; i != 0; i >>= 1, count--)
    if((number & i) != 0) return count;
```

You can get more fancy with optimization.

**EDIT 2** Here's the fastest code I could think of without the use of Bit Scan Reverse opcode. You could use a bigger (256 entry) LUT and remove the last IF statement. In my testing this was faster than the repeated OR-SHIFT then LUT method described in another post.

```
int[] Log2_LUT = new int[16]{0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4};
int Log2 (number) {
int count = 0;
if((number & 0xFFFF0000) != 0) { 
    number >>= 16;
    count += 16;
}
if((number & 0x0000FF00) != 0) { 
    number >>= 8;
    count += 8
}
if((number & 0x000000F0) != 0) {
    number >>= 4;
    count += 4;
}
return count + Log2_LUT[number];
}
```

Or if your in x86 or x86-64 bit architecture you can use the BSR (Bit Scan Reverse) opcode.
You can find the c++ intrinsic for it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbxyd7zd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Also you question is similar to this one [What is the fastest way to calculate the number of bits needed to store a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721244/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-calculate-the-number-of-bits-needed-to-store-a-number)

*EDIT* Why the log2 answers are not optimal...
While mathematically correct, complex floating point operations (sine, cosine, tan, log) are the slowest performing operations on modern computers. This is compounded by having to convert integer to a float and having to ceiling/floor it as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try a base-2 logarithm:

```
ceil(log2(n))
```

Comment: how about 1? Zero binary digits?

Comment: The OP is asking for *the fastest possible way*, and using floating-point operations like `log2()` and `ceil()` is certainly not the fastest way for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the integer is at least `1`, the required bits would be:

```
floor(log2(x)) + 1
```

Comment: The OP is asking for *the fastest possible way*, and using floating-point operations like `log2()` and `ceil()` is certainly not the fastest way for this kind of problem.

Comment: Agreed.  I didn't see that.  Voting to close as dupe.

Answer (score 2):

If speed is more important than portability, then some compilers provide a "count leading zeros" function. This compiles to a single machine instruction on some processors including modern x86 and ARM. For example, with GCC:

```
CHAR_BIT * sizeof x - __builtin_clz(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use logarithms:

```
ceil(log2(x))
```

Comment: `floor` is wrong - using the example from the question, `log2(47) = 5.55`; taking the `floor` of that gives 5 instead of the correct 6.

Comment: To be mathematically nit-picky it's `floor(log2(x)) + 1`.

Comment: The OP is asking for *the fastest possible way*, and using floating-point operations like `log2()` and `ceil()` is certainly not the fastest way for this kind of problem.

Comment: `ceil(log2(x))` is incorrect. it should be `floor(log2(x))+1`

Answer (score 0):

One way is this...

```
unsigned int count_bits(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int count = 0;

    if ( n <= 1 )
      return 1;

    do
      count++;
    while( n >>= 1 );

    return count;
}
```