# Find left most one in binary number

Tags: c

I'm working on a code in C that returns the index of the left most 1. It will also need to return -1 if there are no 1 in the binary number. My code resulted in error message from the terminal:

warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Comment: You are missing a right curly bracket there

Comment: That's not all your code - it's missing at least one right-brace. Which, since your error is about reaching the end of the function, is important. Also, think about what it means to have no bits in the number - what value must it have?

Comment: `return -1;` move to after for-loop.

Comment: right brace is added, sorry i left it off.

Comment: where did you define number_of_bits? Unless the compiler can tell it must be greater than zero, it must assume the for loop may not execute, and then you get to the end of the function without returning any value. Which explains the warning

Comment: @Paul, number_of_bits is a hardcoded number. It will remain unchanged in this program.

Comment: How did you hard code it? You know it is not going to change, but the compiler may not

Comment: @Paul, all i did was: int i = 64;

Comment: Other duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671815/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-highest-set-bit-msb-in-an-i, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589096/find-most-significant-bit-left-most-that-is-set-in-a-bit-array?rq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671815/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-way-to-find-the-highest-set-bit-msb-in-an-i?lq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041837/find-the-index-of-the-highest-bit-set-of-a-32-bit-number-without-loops-obviously?lq=1

Comment: and the compiler may not be able to tell that nothing else in the program can change that (at least add a `const`!). Or as others have said, move the return -1 outside for loop

Answer (score 0):

```
int find_left_most_1 (int input) {
  if (input) {
    int i=number_of_bits;
    for (i=number_of_bits; i>0; i--){
      if (a_function(input,i)==1)
        return i;
    }
    return -1;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't do the obvious check for zero bits

Comment: What is the wrong now ? I can't see any ?? @Paul

Comment: I didn't say it was incorrect. It's just not efficient. What value does `input` have if it has no bits set?

Comment: ah ! You got me on that ! Thanx for correcting !

Comment: My code originally looked like that, but it will return -1 when the input is 1.5, which isn't correct.

Comment: if you use input as an int, why did you inputted a double/float like 1.5 ?