# Simple way to find binary length of cpp_int

Tags: c++, boost, binary

What is a simplest way to find how many bits an arbitrary precision `cpp_int` is?
For example 300 can be represented with a minimum of 9 bits.

I imagine an algorithm that repeatedly right shifts until the value reaches 0, I was wondering if there was a simpler solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to calculate the number of bits needed to store a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721244/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-calculate-the-number-of-bits-needed-to-store-a-number)

Comment: You're basically asking for a fast integer base-2 log, which has a nice answer (not the accepted one though!) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994593/how-to-do-an-integer-log2-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boost has a built-in *most significant bit* operation, see for instance on [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/gen_int.html)

```
cpp_int i = 300;
unsigned int required_bits = msb(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void main()
{
    int n = 0;
    int v = 1;
    int cpp_int = 1003;//any value you like
    for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
    {
        if (v >= cpp_int)
        {
            break;
        }
        v <<= 1;
        n++;
    }
    printf("%d", n);
}
```

//this is for integer no larger that 32 bit representation.hope this helps

Comment: `cpp_int` is a (boost) type, not a variable name in the OP's mind. And `main` must return an `int`. And why use `printf` in C++ ?. And, it doesnt work...

Comment: #include "stdio.h"
void main()
{
 int n = 1;
 cpp_int v = 1;
 int testValue = 1003;//any value you like
 for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(cpp_int）* 8; i++)
 {
  if (v >= testValue )
  {
   break;
  }
  v <<= 1;
  n++;
 }
 printf("%d", n);
}

Comment: printf is used to print the value 'n'. you need to include other header file of boost C++ if necessary. this is just algorithm. I　tested on my computer, if you change cpp_int to standard type int, it works well.

Comment: The binary of '1003' is '1111101011' having 10 bits.

Comment: Sorry, I realize that 'n' should be set to zero at beginning, so you can get the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: I post the image so you can see how it works in standard c++. it's not hard to translate to boost C++, the idea is exactly the same.]

I post the image so you can see how it works in standard c++. it's not hard to translate to boost C++, the idea is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out this method that gives you the number of maximum bits that a number can use. Try this line in your code:

```
int ans = log2(cpp_int)+1;
```

The number of bits needed to represent an integer n is given by rounding down log2(n) and then adding 1 to it.

In general log2(n) gives the power of 2 which is required to get 'n'. If you've read anything about binary numbers you can easily understand why we're using log with base 2.

For the above line to work you've to include 'math.h' header file as:

```
#include <math.h>
```