# Math.log2 precision has changed in Chrome

Tags: javascript, precision

I've written a JavaScript program that calculates the depth of a binary tree based on the number of elements.  My program has been working fine for months, but recently I've found a difference when the web page is viewed in Chrome vs Firefox.

In particular, on Firefox:

```
Math.log2(8) = 3
```

but now in Chrome:

```
Math.log2(8) = 2.9999999999999996
```

My JavaScript program was originally written to find the depth of the binary tree based on the number of elements as:

```
var tree_depth = Math.floor(Math.log2(n_elements)) + 1;
```

I made a simple modification to this formula so that it will still work correctly on Chrome:

```
var epsilon = 1.e-5;
var tree_depth = Math.floor(Math.log2(n_elements) + epsilon) + 1;
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Has anyone else noticed a change in the precision in Chrome recently for `Math.log2`?
2. Is there a more elegant modification than the one I made above by adding epsilon?

Comment: It's a change in V8 actually. And yes, it [has been noticed](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3579). )

Comment: What really amazes me is that a well-known shim (`Math.log2 = function(x) { return Math.log(x) / Math.LN2 };)` actually returns correct results for the precise powers in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks - I think that shim is definitely more elegant than adding epsilon.

Comment: Actually, with `1 << 29` it works fine (because of Math.floor).

Comment: @raina77ow: hmm, interesting. Chrome currently uses the inverse of `LN2` and multiplies that (`log(x) * LOG2E`), so it seems that the rounding error of this shim happens to be on the right side.

Comment: So basically, is 1 << 29 the same as setting epsilon = 1e-30?

Comment: @StefanMusarra: no, that's not the same. `1 << x` is the bitwise equivalent of `Math.pow(2, x)` for 0 < x < 32.

Comment: Actually, they didn't change anything. The key difference between V8 and Firefox's implementation (which I think can be followed through [this issue's thread](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=717379)) , it seems, is that the latter use cache of results.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `Math.round` instead of `Math.floor`?

Comment: @soktinpk: the OP looking for the depth of a binary tree, which doesn't round at the halfway point.

Comment: BTW, if there are 16 elements, isn't the depth of the tree meant to be 4, not 5?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy What do you mean it doesn't round at the halfway point? The depth is meant to be an integer. There is no "halfway point". `Math.round` is just to correct errors (i.e. `Math.round(Math.log2(8)) // --> 3` or `Math.round(Math.log2(64)) // --> 6`. It's like setting `elipson = 0.5`.

Comment: @soktinpk: the number of elements in a binary tree does not have to be a power of two AFAIK.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **Note:** `Math.log2` hasn't actually changed since it's been implemented
> in V8. Maybe you remembered incorrectly or you had included a shim that
> happened to get the result correct for these special cases before Chrome
> included its own implementation of `Math.log2`.
>
> Also, it seems that you should be using `Math.ceil(x)` rather than
> `Math.floor(x) + 1`.

### How can I solve this?

To avoid relying on `Math.log` or `Math.log2` being accurate amongst different implementations of JavaScript (the algorithm used is implementation-defined), you can use bitwise operators if you have less than 2<sup>32</sup> elements in your binary tree. This obviously isn't the fastest way of doing this (this is only O(n)), but it's a relatively simple example:

```
function log2floor(x) {
  // match the behaviour of Math.floor(Math.log2(x)), change it if you like
  if (x === 0) return -Infinity;

  for (var i = 0; i < 32; ++i) {
    if (x >>> i === 1) return i;
  }
}

console.log(log2floor(36) + 1); // 6
```

### How is `Math.log2` currently implemented in different browsers?

The current implementation in Chrome is inaccurate as they rely on multiplying the value of `Math.log(x)` by `Math.LOG2E`, making it susceptible to rounding error ([source](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/math.js?r=24772#236)):

```
// ES6 draft 09-27-13, section 20.2.2.22.
function MathLog2(x) {
  return MathLog(x) * 1.442695040888963407;  // log2(x) = log(x)/log(2).
}
```

If you are running Firefox, it either uses the native `log2` function (if present), or if not (e.g. [on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758001/log2-not-found-in-my-math-h/766669#766669)), uses a similar implementation to Chrome ([source](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/4bb9cac09b222a97c99e3be93419936d1e693d08/js/src/jsmath.cpp#L1028)).

The only difference is that instead of multiplying, they divide by `log(2)` instead:

```
#if !HAVE_LOG2
double log2(double x)
{
    return log(x) / M_LN2;
}
#endif
```

### Multiplying or dividing: how much of a difference *does* it make?

To test the difference between dividing by `Math.LN2` and multiplying by `Math.LOG2E`, we can use the following test:

```
function log2d(x) { return Math.log(x) / Math.LN2; }
function log2m(x) { return Math.log(x) * Math.LOG2E; }

// 2^1024 rounds to Infinity
for (var i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {
  var resultD = log2d(Math.pow(2, i));
  var resultM = log2m(Math.pow(2, i));

  if (resultD !== i) console.log('log2d: expected ' + i + ', actual ' + resultD);
  if (resultM !== i) console.log('log2m: expected ' + i + ', actual ' + resultM);
}
```

Note that no matter which function you use, they still have floating point errors for certain values<sup>1</sup>. It just so happens that the floating point representation of `log(2)` is less than the actual value, resulting in a value *higher* than the actual value (while `log2(e)` is lower). This means that using `log(2)` will round down to the correct value for these special cases.

<sup>1:</sup> `log(pow(2, 29)) / log(2) === 29.000000000000004`

Comment: Slightly related: http://jsperf.com/integer-log2/6 (all of them produce integer log2, in case that's not obvious)

Comment: I opened a new blank instance of both Chrome and Firefox, went to developer tools console, and entered Math.log2(8).  I still get 3 in Firefox and 2.9999999999999996 in Chrome, so I don't think I have a shim causing the difference.

Comment: @StefanMusarra: sorry if I didn't make it clear. Sometimes people add code to support `Math.log2` in browsers that don't have the function yet, so they'll add something like `if (!Math.log2) Math.log2 = function (x) { return Math.log(x) / Math.LN2 };`. If you had previously tested this before Chrome added the `Math.log2` function, your results will now be different compared to before.

Answer (score -1):

You could perhaps do this instead

```
// Math.log2(n_elements) to 10 decimal places
var tree_depth = Math.floor(Math.round(Math.log2(n_elements) * 10000000000) / 10000000000);
```