# How can this method be changed to return a List of Strings rather than a String?

Tags: java, string, tostring, gmp

Recently I begun using GMP in Java through a wrapper (From this [Github](https://github.com/dfdeshom/GMP-java) repo) for some calculations involving extreme numbers.
By 'extreme', I mean numbers sometimes with more than 700 milion digits.

Everything is working absolutely fine, but one calculation I am planing to make is estimated to produce a number with about 8 bilion digits and although the GMP library can handle that and the machine which will execute the code has more than enough memory, the problem is that the only way of getting this number in base 10 is through the method `toString(int base)` (or simply `toString()`) which returns a String containing the number at the specified base, but since a String relies on a `char` array to hold the letters, it will not be able to hold 8 bilion letters since the max array size is arround `2^32-6` if I'm not mistaken.

Unfortunately appart from Java I dont know any other language well enough...

Therefore my question is, how can the GMP wrapper (and possibly native code) be changed in order to return a `List<String>` rather than a single `String` with the digits?
And if this is too hard or even impossible, is there any other alternative I have in Java to deal with numbers that large?

Thank you!

Comment: @azurefrog Same problem, 8 billion digits can't be converted to a `String`. I wonder what OP plans to do with those 8 billion digits.

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer how to modify some code without knowing what the code looks like now.

Comment: @tradeJmark If you refer to my code, modifying it will not solve the problem because the barrier is the String lying between my code and the GMP wrapper mentioned above. If this method can somehow be changed then it will all be fine.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks for the clarification on my behalf! :)

Comment: Why do you need the number in base ten as a string?

Comment: @clabe45 It is used for research. Long storry which is a bit irrelevant to this problem. It has to be base 10 and be saved in a file :(

Comment: On which class are you calling the `toString(int base)` method?

Comment: I assume you are talking about the `toString(int base)` method in https://github.com/dfdeshom/GMP-java/blob/master/org/dfdeshom/math/GMP.java (to clarify the question)

Comment: @toongeorges Indeed. Thats why i need help because i can't understand or edit the native code myself as it goes beyond my knowledge at the moment and also because i cant think of another way to deal with numbers that big...

Comment: I think the library should provide a `private native List<String> natToStringList(int base)` method next to the `private native String natToString(int base)` method. There is not much you can do about it from within Java.

Comment: @toongeorges That sounds reasonable. Unfortunately my understanding of the native code is minimal and i personally cannot add that so im in the hunt for someone who can modify the above wrapper if that is possible to implement this method or a new way of aproaching such large numbers all togeather. BigInteger doesn't suit the task even with such a method implemented in it as multiplication is too slow and it enters a deadlock state somehow for large enough numbers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the type of the number, so assuming BigInteger. Try this.

UPDATE: created the variable `DIGITS_PER_STRNG`, so you can control the number of digits per one `String` item.

```
class Sample {

    private static void test_num_to_string() {
        List<String> list = intToStringList(sampleBigInt());
    }

    private static final int DIGITS_PER_STRNG = 10; // DIGITS_PER_STRNG < Integer.MAX_VALUE ( = max String length)
    private static final BigInteger DIVIDER = BigInteger.valueOf(10);

    private static List<String> intToStringList(BigInteger i) {
        List list = new ArrayList();

        while (i.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0) {
            String str = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < DIGITS_PER_STRNG; j ++) {
                BigInteger[] divideAndRemainder = i.divideAndRemainder(DIVIDER);
                str = str + String.valueOf(divideAndRemainder[1]);
                i = divideAndRemainder[0];
            }
            list.add(str);
            System.out.println(str);
        }

        return list;
    }

    private static BigInteger sampleBigInt() {
        BigInteger bigInt = BigInteger.valueOf((int) Math.pow(2, 10000));
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
            bigInt = bigInt.multiply(bigInt);
        }
        return bigInt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but with BigInteger come some other BigDisadvantages when dealing with huge numbers like the ones above, and i have noticed that when multiplying a number with aprox. 400 milion digits with another large number ( 7 digit) it enters a weird deadlock state so given this and performance i am using GMP which is basically just native code instead of java code... Although your answer doesnt solve my problem i think it shall stay here for other people seeking something similar with BigInteger because it is indeed very informative :- )

Comment: Update: I realised how stupid i was, i could easily adapt this code to GMP and so i've done! Thank you eversomuch it really helped. The string produced is the number in base 10 written backwards but thats easy to fix, simply invert it! Now my question is, how do i determine the correct constant used to divide the number with during the conversion to String? In your example it is `10000000000` but i dont know how to optimise that :S
Again, thanks a ton!

Comment: ok, I edited my post.
If you don't care about the performance, simply call:
`DIGITS_PER_STRING = Integer.MAX_VALUE`
but when the target BigInteger is large enough, you may consider optimising the division loop by calling:
`DIGITS_PER_STRING = Integer.MAX_VALUE / x`
`private static final BigInteger DIVIDER = BigInteger.valueOf(10).pow(x);`
where `x` is about 10000000 or more. (it should be larger as the target gets larger.)
On my pc, the `.pow(100000000)` never ended (1min is my limit of patience), for your reference.

Sorry for my poor English. Hope it'll help you

Comment: Aha i see, for one of the numbers with `63145508` digits, using the number `1` followed by 500 zeros but that took 1 hour 10 minutes...  The default toString() method takes maximum a minute for the same number :O So im still in the hunt for a number that can speed this process up a bit :( I checked BigInteger's toString() but they are doing some crazy maths i didn't understand :( 
Again many thanks for your help!!! Your english is absolutely fine, dont worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: I made the connection that GMP objects do not support these plain bitwise operators, but I saw that they have appropriate methods. This is just the logic; you'll have to convert it to your library*

Use bitwise operators to chop your large number into smaller chunks of bits that Java can digest. Then, convert these to strings individually.
First chunk: (you will need to define `MAX_STRING_SIZE`)

```
MAX_STRING_SIZE & largeNumber
```

Second chunk:

```
MAX_STRING_SIZE & (largeNumber >> numbBits(MAX_STRING_SIZE))  // shift right by number of (used) bits in MAX_STRING_SIZE, so it will be aligned for this calculation
```

Third chunk:

```
MAX_STRING_SIZE & (largeNumber >> 2*numbBits(MAX_STRING_SIZE))  // shift twice
```

This pattern can be compressed into a for loop like-wise (along with converting to strings):

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
while (largeNumber > MAX_STRING_SIZE) {
    largeNumber = largeNumber >> numbBits(MAX_STRING_SIZE))  // shift again
    strings.add(Integer.toString(MAX_STRING_SIZE & largeNumber));  // this value will be an integer
}
```

And `numbBits` as defined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/680040/3783155) (I renamed it for clarity):

```
int numbBits(int value) {
    return Integer.SIZE-Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(value);
}
```

Comment: I'm going to give it a try but im not sure if it will produce the correct number. For example lets say that i have the number: `1101110101` which is `885` in base 10. With a `MAX_STRING_SIZE` of lets say `2` (numBits = `2`) it will cut the bit word to the following chunks:
`11` `01` `11` `01` `01` turning those to String individually through Integer.toString() produces:
`2` `1` `2` `1` `1` -> 21211 which is not base 10 for this base 2 number :(

Comment: Yep, just implemented it and indeed the number produced in base 10 is not correct :( Also in your loop did you mean to fist get the lower bit word and then shift the number or have I missunderstood? Because at the moment you shift before getting so the lowest `MAX_STRING_SIZE` bits are lost...

Comment: @fill͡pant͡ You're right. One question though: how does `Integer.toString` turn `11` (binary) into `"2"`? Wouldn't it be `"3"`?

Comment: Ouch! The shame is real... `1+1=2` so my partly-working mind thought that `11` base 2 = 2 0_0 Apologies for that...